# Selecting sites from VCF which have an alt AD > 10

Tags: variant-calling, vcf, bioawk

I have high-depth variant calling created using the HaplotypeCaller with `--output_mode EMIT_ALL_SITES` I'm interested in finding all sites (regardless of genotype call heterozygous or homozygous) where at least one of the **alternative** alleles have an `AD` value (Allelic Depth) greater than 10, *I*.*e*. are supported by more than 10 reads. Also ideally I want back more than just the first alternative allele.  Note that I don't want back lines of VCF were we only see an AD count for the ref allele only.

So in the example VCF snippet below I'm wanting to select lines: 6,7,8,12,13 and 14, which have GT:AD values `1/1:1,988:989` `0/1:116,92` `0/1:220,234` `0/1:62,611` `1/1:0,109` respectively.

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  12908_DIAG
3   187446740   .   T   .   Infinity    .   AN=2;DP=1095;MQ=60.00   GT:AD:DP    0/0:1095:1095
3   187446741   .   C   .   Infinity    .   AN=2;DP=1117;MQ=60.00   GT:AD:DP    0/0:1117:1117
3   187446752   .   A   .   Infinity    .   AN=2;DP=1297;MQ=60.00   GT:AD:DP    0/0:1297:1297
3   187446763   .   C   .   Infinity    .   AN=2;DP=1494;MQ=60.00   GT:AD:DP    0/0:1494:1494
3   187451574   .   C   .   Infinity    .   AN=2;DP=1493;MQ=60.00   GT:AD:DP    0/0:1493:1493
3   187451609   rs1880101   A   G   39794.03    .   AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.859;ClippingRankSum=0.000;DB;DP=995;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.000;QD=24.56;ReadPosRankSum=0.406;SOR=8.234  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:1,988:989:99:39808,2949,0
4   1803279 .   T   G   0   .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-6.652;ClippingRankSum=0.000;DP=245;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=89.753;MLEAC=0;MLEAF=0.00;MQ=59.97;MQRankSum=0.000;ReadPosRankSum=-2.523;SOR=6.357   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:211,23:234:99:0,364,6739
4   1803307 rs2305183   T   C   2486.60 .   AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-5.049;ClippingRankSum=0.000;DB;DP=215;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=1.110;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=59.97;MQRankSum=0.000;QD=11.95;ReadPosRankSum=-0.045;SOR=0.809  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:116,92:208:99:2494,0,3673
4   1803671 .   C   A   0   .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-0.880;ClippingRankSum=0.000;DP=450;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=0;MLEAF=0.00;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.000;ReadPosRankSum=-0.953;SOR=0.572    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:445,2:447:99:0,1272,15958
4   1803681 .   T   C   0   .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.654;ClippingRankSum=0.000;DP=483;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=0;MLEAF=0.00;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.000;ReadPosRankSum=-0.422;SOR=0.664    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:479,2:481:99:0,1408,18538
4   1803703 .   A   G   0   .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.704;ClippingRankSum=0.000;DP=458;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=0;MLEAF=0.00;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.000;ReadPosRankSum=0.299;SOR=0.497 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:454,2:456:99:0,1325,18095
4   1803704 rs2234909   T   C   6676.60 .   AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-2.605;ClippingRankSum=0.000;DB;DP=456;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=1.753;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.000;QD=14.71;ReadPosRankSum=0.324;SOR=0.849   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:220,234:454:99:6684,0,6366
4   1803824 rs2305184   C   G   2030.60 .   AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=8.083;ClippingRankSum=0.000;DB;DP=124;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=6.128;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=60.00;MQRankSum=0.000;QD=16.51;ReadPosRankSum=0.180;SOR=0.096    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:62,61:123:99:2038,0,1766
4   1805296 rs3135883   G   A   3876.03 .   AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=110;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=60.00;QD=29.22;SOR=9.401    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,109:109:99:3890,326,0
```

[A dropbox link for file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gm4pftuk9i1gx6p/test.vcf?dl=1)

I'd initially considered using GATK's SelectVariants but I'm not sure JEXL has the ability to select out what I want specifically other than a blanket AD > 10 which will give me both ref and alt alleles with AD > 10.  Perhaps there is a bioawk solution or something more elaborate with coreutils which could successfully return sites with an alt AD count > 10?

Comment: cross-posted: http://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/comment/40003#Comment_40003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This now works with the development version of Bcftools v1.5 (commit 4f134df). Thanks to Petr Danecek for [adding the feature](https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/639). I expect this feature to make its way into the next release of Bcftools:

```
git clone git://github.com/samtools/htslib.git
git clone git://github.com/samtools/bcftools.git
(cd bcftools; make)

bgzip Test.vcf
./bcftools/bcftools index Test.vcf.gz
./bcftools/bcftools filter -i 'AD[0:1-] > 10' Test.vcf.gz
```

Output without header (I have modified the second line to be tri-allelic to demonstrate the filtering works):

```
3   187451609   rs1880101   A   G   39794   PASS    AC=2;AF=1;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=1.859;ClippingRankSum=0;DB;DP=995;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1;MQ=60;MQRankSum=0;QD=24.56;ReadPosRankSum=0.406;SOR=8.234   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:1,988:989:99:39808,2949,0
4   1803279 .   T   G   0   PASS    AC=0;AF=0;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-6.652;ClippingRankSum=0;DP=245;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=89.753;MLEAC=0;MLEAF=0;MQ=59.97;MQRankSum=0;ReadPosRankSum=-2.523;SOR=6.357 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0/0:211,3,34:234:99:0,364,6739
4   1803307 rs2305183   T   C   2486.6  PASS    AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-5.049;ClippingRankSum=0;DB;DP=215;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=1.11;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.5;MQ=59.97;MQRankSum=0;QD=11.95;ReadPosRankSum=-0.045;SOR=0.809   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:116,92:208:99:2494,0,3673
4   1803704 rs2234909   T   C   6676.6  PASS    AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-2.605;ClippingRankSum=0;DB;DP=456;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=1.753;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.5;MQ=60;MQRankSum=0;QD=14.71;ReadPosRankSum=0.324;SOR=0.849  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:220,234:454:99:6684,0,6366
4   1803824 rs2305184   C   G   2030.6  PASS    AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=8.083;ClippingRankSum=0;DB;DP=124;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=6.128;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.5;MQ=60;MQRankSum=0;QD=16.51;ReadPosRankSum=0.18;SOR=0.096    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:62,61:123:99:2038,0,1766
4   1805296 rs3135883   G   A   3876.03 PASS    AC=2;AF=1;AN=2;DB;DP=110;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1;MQ=60;QD=29.22;SOR=9.401 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,109:109:99:3890,326,0
```

**Edited** (Dec 2020): bcftools filter syntax has been updated, answer now reflects changes found in version v1.11 (not sure at what point these were introduced).  The old query `'AD[1-] > 10'` would produce the error `The FORMAT tag AD can have multiple subfields, run as AD[sample:subfield]`. A discussion of these changes can be found [here](https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/757).

Comment: So just revisiting this and the query now errors in current versions of bcftools: `The FORMAT tag AD can have multiple subfields, run as AD[sample:subfield]`

Comment: Feel free to edit the post. Anyone can...

Comment: Also, thanks for the update!

Comment: Okay I think the answer is now: `'AD[0:1-] > 10'` just testing...

Answer (score 5):

using [vcfilterjs](http://lindenb.github.io/jvarkit/VCFFilterJS.html)

and the following script:

```
function accept(vc)
    {
    var i,j;
    for(i=0;i< vc.getNSamples();++i)
        {
        var genotype = vc.getGenotype(i);
        if(!genotype.hasAD()) continue;
        var ad = genotype.getAD();
        /* loop over AD starting from '1' =  first ALT */
        for(j=1  ;j< ad.length ;++j)
            {
            if(ad[j]>10) return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
accept(variant);
```

usage:

```
java -jar dist/vcffilterjs.jar -f script.js Test.vcf
```

Comment: I think this system you've created looks to be very flexible I'd be very interested in seeing some more walkthroughs and documented examples, on Github because I'm sure it can solve a lot of complex variant filtration issues.

Comment: @MatthewBashton thanks ! and there is a much more faster alternative version since today (not javascript , but 100% java based ) http://lindenb.github.io/jvarkit/VcfFilterJdk.html

Comment: @DanielStandage not braces, just lambdas using **vcffilterjdk** : ` java -jar dist/vcffilterjdk.jar  -e 'return variant.getGenotypes().stream().filter(G->G.hasAD() && java.util.Arrays.stream(G.getAD()).skip(1).filter(AD->AD>10).findAny().isPresent()).findAny().isPresent();' input.vcf `

Comment: Nice I'll have to give the jdk version a go too.  I have no issues your braces or indentation style ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in [Hail](https://hail.is):

```
from hail import *
hc = HailContext()
(hc.import_vcf('test.vcf')
 .filter_variants_expr('gs.exists(g => g.ad[1:].exists(d => d > 10))')
 .export_vcf('filtered.vcf'))
```

This works with any number of samples and will keep the variants where at least one sample has a genotype with an alternate allele support by more than 10 reads.

To verify we got the expected 6 variants:

```
>>> hc.import_vcf('filtered.vcf').count()
(1L, 6L)
```

[`count`](https://hail.is/hail/hail.VariantDataset.html#hail.VariantDataset.count) returns the number of samples (1) and number of variants (6).

Take a look at the [getting started page](https://hail.is/hail/getting_started.html) or [tutorials](https://hail.is/hail/tutorials-landing.html) if you want to try it out!